# Redis async call by c#, using "DatabaseAsync" makes response slower when there are 400-500 requests per second

Tags: c#, asynchronous, redis, redis-cluster, redisclient

when I use:

```
`public call(Func<IDatabase, Task<T>> func){
  var task=func(redisInstance); 
  task.wait();
  return task.Result;
}`
```

call: `call(client => redisInstance.SetMembersAsync(setName))`

It works Fine, but when there are many requests 'CPU' usage increases;

but in second case:

```
`public async call2(Func<IDatabase, Task<T>> func){
   var task=func(redisInstance); 
   return await task.Result;
}`
```

call: `call2(async client => await redisInstance.SetMembersAsync(setName))`

CPU is ok but responses take much time;

any Ideas about this case?
what is wrong in second method?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things I think you could do to improve the wall-clock time speed under load.

1. There are 2 `await`s, and this is because you have double wrapped the result, so it's now `Task<Task<T>>`. Change your call to:

   ```
   call2(client => redisInstance.SetMembersAsync(setName))
   ```
2. You could optimize by removing the implicit synchronization of the continuation after awaiting, by using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, so change your await to:

   ```
   return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
   ```